# Type Error: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, svm

I'm working on initializing for support vector machine and random forest. I'm using pandas, numpy, matplotlib.pyplot.

When I run:

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=50, cmap='autumn');
```

I get a type error:

> TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key

I can use:

```
plt.scatter(X.iloc[:, 0], X.iloc[:, 1], c=y, s=50, cmap='autumn');
```

or even:

```
plt.scatter(X.iloc[:, 0], X.iloc[:, 16], c=y, s=50, cmap='autumn');
```

but then the following code doesn't bring up a correct graph (it doesn't put the scatterplot on the graph):

```
xfit = np.linspace(-1, 3.5)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=50, cmap='autumn');
plt.plot([0.6], [2.1], 'x', color='red', markeredgewidth=2, markersize=10)

for m, b in [(1, 0.65), (0.5, 1.6), (-0.2, 2.9)]:
    plt.plot(xfit, m * xfit + b, '-k')

plt.xlim(-1, 3.5);
```

What do I do? How do I stop getting the slice error?

Comment: How can we know why the plots are “wrong” when we don’t have your data or know what the plots look like? If your plots aren’t showing up on the correct axes, stop using matplotlib’s pyplot interface and use the object-oriented interface instead.

Comment: What is X?  A dataframe or niumpy array?

Comment: If you want to use the slice like in numpy (ex X[:, 0]), you can transform your DataFrame in a Numpy Array with the method `X.to_numpy()`. So, you could do `X = X.to_numpy()` and access the elements with `X[:,0]`.